# What is "Shadow Identifier Declaration" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

While reading [a JavaScript article](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch3.md#scope-from-functions) I came across this term "Shadow Identifier Declaration". Can someone explain what this is? If possible please provide a simple example too.

[image: snapshot from the article]

Comment: There's *shadowing*, but  "Shadow Identifier Declaration" is not a fixed term.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's when you declare an identifier in a scope that hides one that exists in the containing scope:

```
var foo; // The outer one
function example() {
    var foo; // The inner one -- this "shadows" the outer one, making the
             // outer one inaccessible within this function
    // ...
}
```

There are several ways you might shadow something:

1. With a variable declaration (`var`, `let`, `const`), as above
2. With a parameter declaration:

   ```
   var foo; // The outer one
   function example(foo) { // This parameter shadows the outer `foo`
       // ...
   }
   ```
3. With a function declaration:

   ```
   var foo; // The outer one
   function example() {
       function foo() { // This shadows the outer `foo`
       }
       // ...
   }
   ```

...and several others. Anything that declares an identifier within a scope that hides (shadows) one in the containing scope, that's a shadowing declaration/definition.

Comment: Named function statements and catch blocks could also mask outer variables.

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia definition (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing):

> In computer programming, variable shadowing occurs when a variable
>   declared within a certain scope (decision block, method, or inner
>   class) has the same name as a variable declared in an outer scope. At
>   the level of identifiers (names, rather than variables), this is known
>   as name masking. This outer variable is said to be shadowed by the
>   inner variable, while the inner identifier is said to mask the outer
>   identifier. This can lead to confusion, as it may be unclear which
>   variable subsequent uses of the shadowed variable name refer to, which
>   depends on the name resolution rules of the language.

Java example:

```
public class Shadow {
        private int myIntVar = 0;

        public void shadowTheVar(){

            // since it has the same name as above object instance field, it shadows above 
            // field inside this method
            int myIntVar = 5;

            // If we simply refer to 'myIntVar' the one of this method is found 
            // (shadowing a seond one with the same name)
            System.out.println(myIntVar);

            // If we want to refer to the shadowed myIntVar from this class we need to 
            // refer to it like this:
            System.out.println(this.myIntVar);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args){
            new Shadow().shadowTheVar();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For your question consider this code

```
function foo(a) {
var b = 2;
// some code
function bar() {
// ...
}
// more code
var c = 3;
}
```

In this snippet when you try to execute from global scope.

```
bar(); // fails
console.log( a, b, c ); // all 3 fail
```

suppose in the function bar(){ .... } if you have other code like

```
function foo(){
var b = 3;
console.log(b);
}
```

then it means the foo linside the bar is shadowing the foo(a) in the global scope

Answer (score -1):

This error: `TSLint: Shadowed name: 'AccountService'(no-shadowed-variable`
Also appears when you are calling a service class in capital letters.

[Angular framework, typeScript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhBL3.png)

So, if I set it in small letters:
[Same with small letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C42L9.png)

Comment: Nothing special here about TS or classes. The constructor parameter has the same name as an outside identifier, this it shadows it. This is already explainable by how shadowing works - if a parameter has the same name as an outside identifier, the parameter shadows it.