# React JS - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm a noob to React and Typescript and I'm trying to display a few pictures on my products page using map.

page.tsx

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import { bagsTypes } from '../../const/types';
import bags from '../../const/products';

function Products({ bags }: { bags: bagsTypes[] }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {bags.map((bag) => (
        <div key={bag.name}>
          <p>{bag.name}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Products;
```

types.ts

```
export interface bagsTypes {
  name: string;
  imageUrl: string;
}
```

products.ts

```
import { bagsTypes } from './types';

const bags: bagsTypes[] = [
  {
    name: 'bag1',
    imageUrl: '/images/product1.jpg',
  },
  {
    name: 'bag2',
    imageUrl: '/images/product2.jpg',
  },
];

export default bags;
```

Even the `import bags from '../../const/products'; is greyed out, why is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "Shadow Identifier Declaration" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42174100/what-is-shadow-identifier-declaration-in-javascript)

Comment: Where / how are you rendering your `<Products />` component? If you're not passing anything for the `bags` prop, it should have failed compilation

Answer (score 1):

You're defining `bags` as a prop which overrides the `bags` import within the scope of your component.

You should have something like this where you use `Products`...

```tsx
import bags from './path/to/const/products';
import Products from './path/to/page';

// ...

return (
  <Products bags={bags} />
);
```

---

Alternately, use your `bags` constant in `Products` by removing the prop

```tsx
import bags from '../../const/products';

function Products() {
  return (
    <div>
      {bags.map((bag) => (
        <div key={bag.name}>
          <p>{bag.name}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Products;
```

Answer (score 0):

remove bags import, because you already get it from props

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import { bagsTypes } from '../../const/types';
import bags from '../../const/products'; // remove this line

function Products({ bags }: { bags: bagsTypes[] }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {bags.map((bag) => (
        <div key={bag.name}>
          <p>{bag.name}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Products;
```